# Understanding a very old compiler program

Tags: compilation

I am going through a paper by D.V.Schorre , named " A syntax oriented compiler writing language " . It first begins by attempting to compile a program written in a language named " VALGOL I" and the compiler is written in a language named "META II " .

The following is what the author terms as a compiler program for the language :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMIJX.png)

I want to understand  :

1. Is this the translation of a specific program written in VALGOL1 into a program in METAII ?

or

2.Are these equations which define which keywords in VALGOL1 are equivalent of(to be replaced with , maybe as in a macro ) which keywords of METAII ?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like a description of the grammar of the source language (VALGOL1) with statements that emit the translation to the target language. If I understood well, I think that "META II" is not the target language, but the language in which the translator is written (and this would fit well with "Meta").

Lex and Yacc are more recent (though quite old) tools doing similar things, see [1] for a tutorial (you will see that Yacc definition files has several similarities with your example file).

[1] http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/

Comment: "Description of the grammar " means how to interpret(not the technical meaning of this word) a certain command in VALGOL1 in  METAII? So, what do you suggest (1) or (2) in my question ?

Comment: I think it is more 2.

Comment: Hopefully , I can sail through the rest of the paper assuming this